# Trouble reloading UICollectionView's supplementary view (header) with invalidationContext

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a use case where I have a `UICollectionView` used to display photos. This collection view has a supplementary view (header) that displays the photo count.

My business logic requires at some point to `insertItems(at:)` or `removeItems(at:)` from the collection view so the supplementary view needs to get reloaded in order for the photo count to be updated.

I am looking for a generic solution (a `UICollectionView` extension would be favourable) to be able to reload/refresh **just** the collection view's supplementary view.

I **do not want** solutions that:

- Reload entire sections of the collection view
- Reload data of the collection view
- Redraw or reload anything other than the supplementary view

I just need something that triggers `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` and redraws the supplementary view.

I have tried this, but it crashes with generic `NSException`:

```
 self.photosCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section:0)])

 let context = UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext()
                context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])

 let layout = self.photosCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
                layout?.invalidateLayout(with: context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your insert item method and delete item method, just assign the count to the header view label this way you don't have to reload the collection view

```
let headerView = collectionViewDemo.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: [0,0]) as? DemoCollectionReusableView
            headerView?.textLabel.text = self.count
```